# (discord.js) How do I get my bot to create a voice channel that counts ONLY the online members IN voice channels?

Tags: server, statistics, discord.js

The picture here shows an example of it. There's 8 people online in voice channel but they're all separate and around, and even bots. so I want a bot to count that.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9MB2.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, nor a service to get suggestions about how to implement a feature. Take a crack at this issue yourself, and if you encounter issues, create a question here with the code you tried. As for how to do this, take a look at the docs for [guild member manager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) and [voice states](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=voice). You need to filter all members in the guild whose `member.voice.channel` is defined, and count them.